# Reopen request: Daily schedule of a composer

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

Just calling attention to the title question [Daily schedule of a composer](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/108873/daily-schedule-of-a-composer).

I've voted to reopen. From the comments:

> Voting to re-open: I think this question fits well within the "constructive subjective" question criteria and well-considered answers would be very useful to student or aspiring-student composers.

So, my call out to like-minded reopen voters.

And as [Bartles & Jaymes once said](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hYdWHK6AA6E&t=28s), "thank you very much for your support."<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Okay, actually only Bartles -- [played by David Rufkahr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bartles_%26_Jaymes) -- ever spoke. You got me there.</sub>

Comment: I currently think as worded, it won't really work on the site. The core question seems to be "What do you practice and how much? " which is definitely posing to be an endless list where everyone's routine is valid which isn't a good Q&A question (but would be fine for our chat). If it can be edited to be more objective I'd support a reopening.

Comment: I feel so torn wrt to the topic. But I wholeheartedly support bringing it up here on meta. +1

Answer (score 3):

I felt that the question was too based in opinion and other personal matters. Some composers may pull an Asimov and write from 9 to 5 Monday through Friday; others may only write when it comes to them. And because all of these answers are "correct" for the people that write them, suddenly these answers strike me as meaningless for the OP. If all answers are correct, then is there really even a reason to search for answers?

In addition to this, I think the question is ultimately asking for a list: "What are some examples of schedules of active composers?" And this is a type of question explicitly to be avoided.

With that said, I can understand your argument; I do think there is some daylight here between opinion-based and constructive-subjective. And democracy should absolutely prevail, so if our community reopens the question, my job is to step aside and enjoy the answers that come in.

Comment: I agree with you Richard, that it is entirely opinion-based. The 4 composers I know are all entirely different in their habits

Comment: @DoktorMayhem you just answered the question in a comment on meta ...